# Retrieve exchange rate from website with Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a date in Excel and get the rate on this date .

I search solutions but not found something that can help me.

I am using Excel 2016.

My code:

```
Function CryptoQuote(enteredDate As String)
    If IsDate(enteredDate) Then
        enteredDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Dim strURL As String: strURL = "http://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & enteredDate
        MsgBox strURL
        Dim http As Object: Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        http.Open "GET", strURL, False
        http.Send
        Dim strCSV As String
        Found = InStr(http.responseText, "/graph/?from=USD&amp;to=ILS") 'find this in the HTML
        If Found <> 0 Then
            Length = Len(http.responseText) - Found 'check the length of the HTML
            strCSV = Right(http.responseText, Length) 'Trim the begining of the String until we get to our value
            strCSV = Left(strCSV, Len(strCSV) - (Len(strCSV) - 36)) 'Trim the end of the string to leave only the value we are looking for
            strCSV = Replace(strCSV, "graph/?from=USD&amp;to=ILS'>", "") 'replace the original search string with nothing so we are left with numbers only
        Else
        CryptoQuote = "Could not find the data!"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a correct date as yyyy-mm-dd"
    End If
    CryptoQuote = Val(strCSV)
    MsgBox strCSV
End Function
```

Comment: Get the rate of what? From where?

Comment: Foreign Exchange Rate?  Like GBP/USD? Try yahoo finance.

Comment: I want get rate of USD by history date in Excel. How can I use yahoo finance in excel?

Comment: against which currency?

Comment: USD to ILS/EUR.

Comment: Try this https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-ils-historical-data

Comment: It's perfect but how can I get value by date in cell excel?

Comment: The VLOOKUP worksheet function

Comment: But it's not update automatically, I want the data will be online.

Comment: You have to pay Bloomberg for live data or perhaps http://www.xe.com/

Comment: Maybe post your code first? Since this is under VBA...
What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? Other than that: Setup a connection using Excel's built-in functionality to load your data. Afterwards it's just a matter of VLookup.

Comment: i added my code

Comment: PLease tag your version of Excel. Since version 2013, MS introduced some webservices functions and that could impact the answer

Comment: excel 2016.....

Comment: You might want to search the web for the solution stipulated by @PatrickHonorez: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/-yahoo-finance-pull-stock-information-excel-spreadsheet OR https://kx.cloudingenium.com/content-providers/how-to-obtain-stock-quotes-from-yahoo-finance-you-can-query-them-via-excel-too/ OR http://www.financial-modelling.net/tutorials/excel/open-excel-retrieve-stock-quotes-in-a-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is USD to EUR then this will do the job (not the most elegant way of doing things but it will do the task at hand):

```
Public Sub CryptoQuote()
    enteredDate = InputBox("Please enter the search date: ", "Enter Date")
    If IsDate(enteredDate) Then
        enteredDate = Format(enteredDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Dim strURL As String: strURL = "http://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & enteredDate
        Dim http As Object: Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        http.Open "GET", strURL, False
        http.send
        Dim strCSV As String
        Found = InStr(http.responsetext, "/graph/?from=USD&amp;to=EUR") 'find this in the HTML
        If Found <> 0 Then
            Length = Len(http.responsetext) - Found 'check the length of the HTML
            strCSV = Right(http.responsetext, Length) 'Trim the begining of the String until we get to our value
            strCSV = Left(strCSV, Len(strCSV) - (Len(strCSV) - 36)) 'Trim the end of the string to leave only the value we are looking for
            strCSV = Replace(strCSV, "graph/?from=USD&amp;to=EUR'>", "") 'replace the original search string with nothing so we are left with numbers only
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not find the data!"
        End If
    Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a correct date as yyyy-mm-dd"
    End If
    MsgBox "The rate for 1 USD in EURO is " & strCSV
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much! can i calling CryptoQuote as a UDF (user defined function)?

Comment: No problem,.. Of course you can call the Subroutine from other places too, I guess it's probably best if you play with it and see what you are able to do.. Any issues, I will be happy to help. :)

Comment: hi friend, i change my code, thats always return me the date of today.

Comment: If you are going to pass the enteredDate as a string, maybe you should also remove the If IsDate(enteredDate) Then, as it will not be a date, it will be a string instead, also you should do some validation before you call the macro to make sure that the date is formatted correctly... but yeah this should work also...

Comment: thank you.. i removed         enteredDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: Nope, I mean remove the IF statement and the End if, but you should leave the Format(Date, to make sure that the string is formatted correctly before calling the URL...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub gethtmltable()
    Dim objWeb As QueryTable
    Dim sWebTable As String
     'You have to count down the tables on the URL listed in your query
     'This example shows how to retrieve the 2nd table from the web page.
    sWebTable = 2
     'Sets the url to run the query and the destination in the excel file
     'You can change both to suit your needs

    LValue = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Set objWeb = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;http://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & LValue, _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))

    With objWeb

        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = sWebTable
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With
    Set objWeb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

They changed to HTTPS, so make sure that you use `https://www.x-rates.com` over `http://www.x-rates.com`. The rest works fine without changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
~~~
Sub UpdateFX()
Dim XML_Object As Object
Dim HTMLResponse  As String
Dim ECB_FX_URL As String
Dim FXstring As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim USDVal As Variant, GBPVal As Variant, CADVal As Variant
Dim FXDate As Variant, PrevDate As Variant
Dim FxTable()
Dim MidSt As Integer, MidLen As Integer
Dim MnthEnd As Boolean
Dim FirstRptDate As Date, CurRptDate As Date
Dim DateLoops As Integer


' Modified by ANY1, Feb. 17, 2021
' To run properly, MSXML needs to be referenced in Excel
' To do this, complete the following steps:
' 1. Open Visual Basic Editor (VBE) from Excel
' 2. Select Tool - References
' 3. Scroll through the list of available references and select the latest version of Microsoft XML, v 6.0 (latest as of Feb. 17, 2021)
' 4. You should also select (a) Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library and (b) Microsoft Internet Controls
' You may also want to select Microsoft HTML Object Library, but this is not strictly required for this code to run
' The URL accesses an XML download of the ECB's daily FX Quotes back to 1999

ECB_FX_URL = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml?affd3fe4c0ac916ce2e9d1ccfea2327c"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
Application.StatusBar = "Downloading XML string from ECB"
Set XML_Object = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
XML_Object.Open "GET", ECB_FX_URL, False
XML_Object.send
HTMLResponse = XML_Object.responseText

' Find the first and last dates in the XML string
MidSt = InStr(HTMLResponse, "Cube time=") + 11
MidLen = InStr(MidSt, HTMLResponse, Chr(34)) - MidSt
FXstring = Mid(HTMLResponse, MidSt, MidLen)
CurRptDate = Mid(HTMLResponse, MidSt, MidLen)

' Calculate the maximum number of business days between the first and last report dates, ignoring holiday absences
' To find the last date, you need to Truncate the XML string to the last 2000 characters, otherwise, the count will exceed Excel's limits on the size of integers.
FXstring = Right(HTMLResponse, 2000)
MidSt = InStrRev(FXstring, "Cube time=") + 11
MidLen = InStr(MidSt, FXstring, Chr(34)) - MidSt
FirstRptDate = Mid(FXstring, MidSt, MidLen)
DateLoops = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(FirstRptDate, CurRptDate)

ReDim FxTable(1 To DateLoops, 1 To 8)

' Clear old data
' I've created a named range in my data worksheet called "FX_Download". This is the top left cell of the range which will hold the target data.
' There should at least two blank rows above the this named range to hold the URL that is pasted into the worksheet and a reference to the source

If Range("FX_Download") <> "" Then
    Range(Range("FX_Download"), Range("FX_Download").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7)).Clear
End If

With Range("FX_Download")
    .Offset(-2, 0) = "ECB Web page source:"
    .Offset(-1, 0) = ECB_FX_URL
    .Offset(0, 0) = "Bus. Date"
    .Offset(0, 1) = "Month End"
    .Offset(0, 2) = "USD"
    .Offset(0, 3) = "GBP"
    .Offset(0, 4) = "CAD"
    .Offset(0, 5) = "USDGBP"
    .Offset(0, 6) = "EURGBP"
    .Offset(0, 7) = "CADGBP"
    With Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(0, 7))
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End With

' Reset the FXstring to the original HTMLResponse
FXstring = HTMLResponse
j = 1
Application.StatusBar = "Parsing XML string to extract USD & GBP quotes for each date"

For i = 1 To DateLoops
    if i mod 250 = 0 then Application.StatusBar = "Parsing XML string to extract USD and GBP quotes for each date. Loop Number: " & i & " of " & Format(DateLoops, "0,000") & "."
    ' Loop through XML response text, looking for each new date. The date is preceded by text which starts with the search text "Cube time="
    ' Truncate the string by eliminating the portion of the string prior to and including the search text
    ' Extract all text starting after this occurence and then look for the specific currency quotes
    ' Adjust the starting point by 9 (length of the search text). Since we're counting from the Right it is -9.
    FXstring = Right(FXstring, Len(FXstring) - InStr(1, FXstring, "Cube time=") - 9)
    ' Now that the FXstring is truncated, extract the date
    ' Store the date of this quote in the FXDate variable, after extracting any quotes (") from the text.
    ' Chr(34) is the code for the " symbol
    FXDate = Left(FXstring, InStr(FXstring, Chr(34) & ">"))
    FXDate = Replace(FXDate, Chr(34), "", 1)
    
    ' Data starts from the most recent date and moves to earlier dates.
    ' Check to see whether the new date is from an earlier month.
    ' If it is, set the MnthEnd variable to TRUE. Also set to TRUE for the first date in the series
    If i = 1 Then
        MnthEnd = True
    Else
        If Month(FXDate) <> Month(PrevDate) Then
            MnthEnd = True
        Else
            MnthEnd = False
        End If
    End If
    
    If MnthEnd Then
        ' For new Month Ends, extract the specific currency quotes which follow the text "USD" rate="
        ' The code Chr(34) is used to place the " symbol in the search string
        
        ' MidSt finds the starting point for the FX quote
        ' MidLen finds the length of the FX quote by searching for the next occurence of the " symbol, starting from the MidSt point
        ' The the Mid() function extracts that date from the XML string
        MidSt = InStr(FXstring, "USD" & Chr(34) & " rate=") + 11
        MidLen = InStr(MidSt, FXstring, Chr(34)) - MidSt
        USDVal = Mid(FXstring, MidSt, MidLen)
        
        ' Repeat with search adapted for GBP
        MidSt = InStr(FXstring, "GBP" & Chr(34) & " rate=") + 11
        MidLen = InStr(MidSt, FXstring, Chr(34)) - MidSt
        GBPVal = Mid(FXstring, MidSt, MidLen)
        
        ' Repeat with search adapted for CAD
        MidSt = InStr(FXstring, "CAD" & Chr(34) & " rate=") + 11
        MidLen = InStr(MidSt, FXstring, Chr(34)) - MidSt
        CADVal = Mid(FXstring, MidSt, MidLen)
        
        ' Use the value rather than the EoMonth formula to populate the cells for the month-end date.
        ' If the formula is used the Range.Find function won't work when searching for dates.
        
        ' Write data to FxTable array, including the GBP cross rates that are calculated from the original EUR rates
        FxTable(j, 1) = FXDate
        FxTable(j, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(FXDate, 0)
        FxTable(j, 3) = USDVal
        FxTable(j, 4) = GBPVal
        FxTable(j, 5) = CADVal
        FxTable(j, 6) = USDVal / GBPVal
        FxTable(j, 7) = 1 / GBPVal
        FxTable(j, 8) = CADVal / GBPVal
        
        j = j + 1
    End If
    PrevDate = FXDate
    If FXDate = FirstRptDate Then
    ' Check to see if the FirstRptDate has been reached.
    ' If it has, set i to end the loops
        MidSt = i
        i = DateLoops
    End If
Next i


With Range(Range("FX_Download").Offset(1, 0), Range("FX_Download").Offset(DateLoops, 7))
    .Select
    .Value = FxTable
    .NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

With Range(Range("FX_Download").Offset(1, 0), Range("FX_Download").Offset(DateLoops, 1))
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = "FX Update complete. Downloaded " & MidSt & " data points and created " & j - 1 & " month-ends."

End Sub
```